# How can you put a php function inside of an html form inside of a php echo?

Tags: php, forms, function, paypal, echo

I am trying to make a paypal checkout button, the button works fine when it is not inside of an echo, but when I put the button inside of an echo because I need it to dynamically be produced, it has a problem referencing the "paypal_items();" function, which is what adds all of the items that a user has in their cart. The button works, it redirects to the paypal website but it says there are no items (which makes me believe that the paypal_items() isn't getting reached. I've tried a bunch of different syntaxes but I can't figure anything out and I'm wondering if this is even possible because it's inside a form which is furthermore inside of an echo.

There is a lot more that happens in cart(), I just erased most of it because it seemed unnecessary, it basically gathers the session data for what is in the cart and then echo's it for the buyer to see.

```
function paypal_items() { //this function takes the cart and organizes all the variables in a way that paypal can read it (this function is called on in the paypal send form)
$num = 0;
foreach($_SESSION as $name => $value) {
    if ($value!=0) {
        if(substr($name, 0, 5)=='cart_') {
            $id = substr ($name, 5, strlen($name)-5);
            $get = mysql_query ('SELECT id, name, price FROM products WHERE id='.mysql_real_escape_string((int)$id));
            while ($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc ($get)) {
                $num++;
                echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_number_'.$num.'" value="'.$id.'">'; //This num and number from database listing is flip flopped.
                echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_name_'.$num.'" value="'.$get_row['name'].'">';
                echo '<input type="hidden" name="amount_'.$num.'" value="'.$get_row['price'].'">';
                echo '<input type="hidden" name="shipping_'.$num.'" value="'.$get_row['shipping'].'">'; //Cost of Shipping first item.
                echo '<input type="hidden" name="shipping2_'.$num.'" value="'.$get_row['shipping'].'">'; //Cost of shipping two or more items is applied (shipping is multiplied depending on quantity)
                echo '<input type="hidden" name="quantity_'.$num.'" value="'.$value.'">';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
function cart() {
    if ($total = 0) {
           // Empty Cart Alert..
    }

    else {
        echo '<div class="checkoutBtn">'.'<p>
              <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
                 <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
                 <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
                 <input type="hidden" name="business" value="blah@blahblah.com">
                 <?php paypal_items(); ?>
                 <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
                 <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="echo number_format($total, 2);">
                 <input type="image" src="images/cartPage/checkoutBtn.gif" width="247" height="54" name="submit" alt="Secure Checkout With PayPal!">
              </form>
            </p>;'.'</div>'.
    }
}
```

Comment: You're using <?php ?> tags inside of an echo. Delete those tags and it should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
function cart() {
    if ($total = 0) {
           // Empty Cart Alert..
    }

    else {
        echo '<div class="checkoutBtn"><p>
              <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
                 <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
                 <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
                 <input type="hidden" name="business" value="blah@blahblah.com">';
        paypal_items();
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
                 <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="'.number_format($total, 2).'">
                 <input type="image" src="images/cartPage/checkoutBtn.gif" width="247" height="54" name="submit" alt="Secure Checkout With PayPal!">
              </form>
            </p></div>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Euhm the           `<?php tags are on the wrong place.`

Try this:

```
     <?php
    function cart() {
if ($total = 0) {
          // Empty Cart Alert..
  }
else {
    echo '<div class="checkoutBtn">'.'<p>
          <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
             <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
             <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
             <input type="hidden" name="business" value="blah@blahblah.com">
              paypal_items();
             <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
             <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="echo number_format($total, 2);">
             <input type="image" src="images/cartPage/checkoutBtn.gif" width="247" height="54" name="submit" alt="Secure Checkout With PayPal!">
          </form>
        </p>;'.'</div>'.
   }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I had already tried that with no luck. The problem I think is that the paypal_items is ECHOING inside of an ECHO....so its outputting twice which just doesn't work? I needed to do what the guy below you said, break up the echo into two echo's and just have the function sitting inbetween.